# Is there any way to send a specific column to the where clause of Entity-framework Core update command?

Tags: .net, orm, entity-framework-core

I have a table list of items which has GUID as the key also it has customerId who the item belongs, I want to apply security in the row level in which every command updating a row should have the right CustomerId. In this case, I do not want to first fetch the item and check if it belongs to the customer who is trying to update the row and then send the update to the table.
I was thinking it was possible to intercept and update the where clause I could add CustomerId to the generated query.
If it is not, is it a good practice to add CustomerId as part of the key (a work-around to add CustomerId in the generated update)? any other workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you can do so and the command will let you know that a record was NOT updated.  How will you know *why* it wasn't updated?  It could be the ID wasn't found or it could be that the user is not authorized by your criteria.  For web requests, that's the difference between a 404 Not Found and a 403 Forbidden response (which is important to log as you'd like to know if someone's trying to goof around with data that's not theirs, yes?).

An alternative to always loading the entity first could be to cache the relevant data (indexed by type & PK value, payload of `CustomerID`) for a period of time then check the cache to compare the `CustomerID` property when an update is requested.  If an entity doesn't exist in the cache, you'd of course have to load it, but if you use the same service/app to get and update entities, the cache should contain the relevant data much of the time.  This, of course, only works if you don't expect the `CustomerID` to change in the database.